# How to edit body before send request with Fiddler(script)

Tags: fiddler, fiddler-dev

How to edit body before send request with Fiddler(script)

in my case path /login
have body
username: xxx
pass: xxxx

how to edit user pass before send send request

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please show what you have tried so we can help you!

Comment: i don't know command to set req boby sir

Comment: i can set header by oSession.oRequest["NewHeaderName"] = "New header value";  but cannot set body request

Comment: Well, since I do not know exactly what you are looking for, this might not be spot on for you. Anyway, a very quick lookup with Google gave me this: http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.com/2013/09/set-username-and-password-for-basic.html

Answer (score 1):

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    var loginDomain = 'www.testlogin.org';  
    var loginPath = '/login';
    var username;
    var password;
    var strBody
    
    if (username == null && oSession.uriContains(loginDomain) && 
        oSession.uriContains(loginPath))
    {

        username = FiddlerObject.prompt("Enter user name: ");
        password = FiddlerObject.prompt("Enter password: ");
        strBody='username: ' + username + ' pass: ' + password;
        //encode the body to handle special characters in the password
        //password "P&ssword=secure"    will be    "P%26ssword%3Dsecure"                                            
        strBody=Utilities.UrlEncode(strBody);
        oSession.utilSetRequestBody(strBody);
    }

//... the rest of the OnBeforeRequest function
}
```

This will open 2 prompt windows to enter the username and then password
after entering the login URL in a browser and executing a request. The prompts may not popup in front of the browser, you may need to switch focus to fiddler to use the prompt windows

Answer (score 0):

For modifying requests in Fiddler classic use the `OnBeforeResponse` function. To replace username and password in body of the HTTP request (not in header as used e.g. by BASIC auth) you can use `utilReplaceInRequest` method which performs search and replace on text level:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    // check if the requests is to the correct hosts and path
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.example.org") && oSession.PathAndQuery.Contains("/login")) {
        oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        oSession.utilReplaceInRequest("username: xxx", "username: newusername");
        oSession.utilReplaceInRequest("pass: xxxx", "pass: newpassword");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can get the body as text and manipulate it as you want using standard [.Net String methods](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-sharp-strings):

```
    if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.example.org") && oSession.PathAndQuery.Contains("/login")) {
        oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        var body = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
        // use .Net String manipulation methods to find and replace text in the body
        oSession.utilSetRequestBody(body);
    }
```

Comment: how can i set when i don't know value of object i want to set like this obj["username"] = "teeraphong" not use replace method sir because i don't know value to replace